# how to get only parent category posts in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

I want to get the only top parent categories(cat_id=1) list  in the front page.
For that I have written this  While loop in home page.

```
<div class="left col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
        <?php
            while(have_posts()) {
                the_post(); ?>
                <div class="content-block col-xs-12">
                    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
                    <hr class="color-strip">
                    <p><?php echo wp_trim_words(get_the_content(), 11); ?></p>
                    <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue reading &raquo;</a></p>
                    <div class="tags"><ul><li><?php the_tags(); ?></li></ul></div>
                </div>
                <hr/>
        <?php }?>

    </div>
```

But its bringing all the subcategories also. I want to keep the list of only one category. What change do I have to make in the if condition.

Comment: I don't see an if statement in the code you posted. Is this the whole code sample? Also, how are you retrieving the posts?

Comment: Yes I am looking for what I have to wire in if condition to bring only what is in cat_id=1. cat _id=1 have lots of sub categories and they have lots of posts. But I want only what is in parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the categories using [`get_categories()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/) and you can get all of the top level categories with:

```
$categories = get_categories(
    array(
        'parent' => 0
    )
);
```

Then, something like this should work for you to get only posts within top level categories.

```
$categories = get_categories(
    array(
        'parent' => 0
    )
);

$categoryArray = array();

foreach( $categories as $category ) {
    $categoryArray[] = $category->ID;
}

function exclude_category($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', implode(',', $categoryArray) );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```

This will get all of the top level categories and then set them in the main query.

Answer (score 0):

the Following cod partially fixes my problem. Writing a function in functions.php.

```
function exclude_category($query) {
    if ( $query->is_home() ) {
    $query->set('cat', '-5,-6');
    }
    return $query;
    }
    add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category');
```