# WP-Query / pre_get_posts / category / not working

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am trying to get **only** results of the WordPress main-category **without** any child-categories/sub-categories.
Any advice on how to achieve this?

This code is not working:

```
$cat_slug = $_POST['v1'];

function cat_query_filter($query) {
  
    if(!is_admin()) {

        $idObj = get_category_by_slug($cat_slug);
        $cat_id = $idObj->term_id;
        $query->set('category__in', $cat_id );

        };
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'cat_query_filter');
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear.  Where are you trying to only show these results.  What kind of page would this be?  Does this answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49201101/how-to-get-only-parent-category-posts-in-wordpress/49201773

Comment: @howardE Hi, I am using Oxygen Pagebuilder, therefore 
Alternative 1: I can use php-functions at any position on the page I want (main-query already exists).
Alternative 2: I can use Advanced Script plugin and use the "init-hook" to inject PHP early.

The other answer is not helping as they excluding categories by their ID, this is not possible I need to automatically exclude all other sub-categories ;-)

Comment: BTW: Is it possible to use post variables at this stage (and putting them via "global $cat_slug;" into the function) or do I have something to consider?